# Why is my computer constantly using most of my RAM?

Tags: windows, memory

For some reason, my computer is using a large amount of my RAM but I can't figure out what is actually using it ? I know nothing about computers so please help me!

Useful images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have a non-paged pool leak.

Comment: It's not... you just don't understand RAM usage and caching.

Comment: @acejavelin That’s just not true. The non-paged pool isn’t supposed to be that big. On some of my PCs at home, it’s less than 100 MB.

Comment: @DanielB There are many reasons for high non-paged pool usage that are explainable, that alone isn't necessarily a problem and the OP never stated if this is an increasing number over time. I have seen Samsung laptops push 2.5GB due to their "wonderful" tool called Intellimemory

Comment: @acejavelin it is a pool issue. You don't understand memory usage of windows.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Then I will follow this quietly to learn more...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot a good chunk of your memory is being used for caching. This is a good thing. The OS will cache various items (such as files) so as to speed up operations with memory that is not being actively used by programs.

Ideally you want to see minimal memory being reported as free. If you have a lot of memory being reported as free that means that it is h just sitting there and doing you no good.

If your programs need more memory the OS will automatically reduce the amount of memory for caching and use it for programs. This means that the use of memory for caching does not deny programs their memory.

In your first picture that green in use bar is what I'd actually being used. You should add the blue stand by bat and the free bar together for your available RAM.

Comment: no, the non paged pool is too high. this has nothing to do with caching